# amchart 4 working fine on local but after deployment showing multiple lines

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

[image]

I am using this chart for amchart 4 library : https://www.amcharts.com/demos/area-with-time-based-data/?theme=dataviz, Its working fine on my local environment but after deployment showing crazy lines, however values are coming fine. If anyone faced such issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was on my local list was coming sorted in API but on production it was not which was giving this issue.